# Fade in object on page turn in Page View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uivisualeffectview, uiblureffect

I am trying to fade a UIBlur background in as the page is entering in a PageViewController.

For example, Page 1 has no UI Blur on the background, but I want page 2 to fade a Dark Blur on the background of the controller as the page is appearing.

What happens currently is the page appears, the half a second later the blur is applied.

Here's what I have currently for page 2:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var blurEffect: UIVisualEffectView!


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let overlay = blurEffect
            overlay.effect = nil
        }

        override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
            let overlay = blurEffect
            overlay.effect = nil
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
                overlay.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Dark)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried your blur code in `viewWillAppear(_:)`?

Comment: Yes, I want it to fade as it is presenting in the transition to the next page in the Page View Controller :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you actually want, but if you want to present a view controller over another where you are blurring the presenting view controller as the background for the presented view controller. You should:

1. Changing the presented view controller's view's background color to clear color.
2. Adding a UIVisualEffectView at the bottom of the presented view controller's view hierarchy.
3. Changing the segue to a modal segue or present the view controller modally.
4. Change the presentation style of the segue to over current context or setting the presentation of the presented view controller `viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext`
5. Change transition to either Cross Dissolve or Cover Vertical 
   `viewController.modalTransitionStyle = .CoverVertical`

I'm sure you can apply this technique in other ways as well, though it is performance expensive.

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to say it is inside a Page View controller. I am trying to make it fade as it is presenting the next page. I made some edits. I do appreciate the response!

Comment: Are you not happy with the animation or are you not happy with the timing?

Comment: Sadly no, I want it to be responsive and fade as you turn the page. So if you were to only slide half way, it would apply like an alpha of .5 and change as the slide gesture is occurring.

Comment: This is not something you will be able to get out-of-the-box from a PageViewController. You would need to write a UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition. You can read about that here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CustomizingtheTransitionAnimations.html and https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/218/ Kind of beyond the scope of a SO question.

Comment: That helps immensely! Thanks so much. Sorry it's beyond the scope of a SO question, but you seriously helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> The following properties of the UIView class are animatable:
>
> @property frame
>
> @property bounds
>
> @property center
>
> @property transform
>
> @property alpha
>
> @property backgroundColor
>
> @property contentStretch

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/)